# C++ template type inference for lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

Let's say I have this function:

```
template <typename T>
T sum(std::vector<T> const& v) {
    T acc = T();
    for (auto const& e : v) {
        acc += e;
    }
    return acc;
}
```

Here C++ only allows to call this function with vectors, and can automatically infer the T type parameter.

Is there any way I could do the same using lambdas? I know they are semantically same as a functor and I could easily do that there, but I'm interested in lambdas inline. I know I can do this:

```
[](auto& v) { ... }
```

But this matches anything, even non-vector parameters (even if the body causes a compiler error).

Comment: [Coming in C++20](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) :)

Comment: @Quentin That's kind of disappointing, I need workarounds again. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++20, we can specify template arguments following the capture list:

```
auto accum = []<class T>(std::vector<T>& v) {
    auto acc = T{};
    for (auto const& e : v) {
        acc += e;
    }
    return acc;
};
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JlJolqTHTaJ91kdU)

In the interim suppose that for now you're stuck relying on type traits to infer `value_type`:

```
auto accum = [](auto& v) {
    auto acc = typename std::decay_t<decltype(v)>::value_type{};
    for (auto const& e : v) {
        acc += e;
    }
    return acc;
};
```

You could use a `static_assert` if you wanted to enforce particular container(s):

```
auto accum = [](auto& v) {
    using ttype = std::decay_t<decltype(v)>;
    using vtype = typename ttype::value_type;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::vector<vtype>, ttype>);
    auto acc = vtype{};

    for (auto const& e : v) {
        acc += e;
    }
    return acc;
};
```

---

For example:

```
int main(){

    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    std::list<double> l{4.0,5.0,6.0};
    auto accum = [](auto& v) {
        auto acc = typename std::decay_t<decltype(v)>::value_type{};
        for (auto const& e : v) {
            acc += e;
        }
        return acc;
    };

    std::cout << accum(v) << std::endl;
    std::cout << accum(l) << std::endl;
}
```

#### [Demo for any iterable container with a `value_type`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZRaZi6m0ApXzjp9U)

#### [Demo with `static_assert` for `vector` type](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vrN61N4caAknB23I)

---

Since you mentioned that you are not using STL containers, but rather [Phantom Types](https://blog.demofox.org/2015/02/05/getting-strongly-typed-typedefs-using-phantom-types/), then you have two options:

- Add a typedef to your strongly-typed enum like so `using value_type = PHANTOM_TYPE`
- Create a separate traits class to infer `value_type`:

  template 
  struct SUInt
  {
  public:
      SUInt (unsigned int value) : m_value(value) { }
      inline unsigned int& Value () { return m_value; }
  private:
      unsigned int m_value;
  };

  template 
  struct SUInt_traits{};

  template
  struct SUInt_traits>{
      using value_type = T;
  };

Which you can then use from within your lambda [like so](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zcgp5ZsUuEuX81OS):

```
auto do_a_thing = [](auto& v) {
    auto acc =  typename SUInt_traits<std::decay_t<decltype(v)>>::value_type{};
    // ...
};
```

Comment: This would be nice for this exact problem, but I actually have to deal with phantom types in sum-types, this is not a viable solution. Sorry, I brought a wrong example, I should have asked more general I guess.

Comment: @PeterLenkefi: I don't understand why you are summing phantom types?

Comment: My problem is actually pretty complicated, I could explain in chat if you are interested.

Comment: @PeterLenkefi: No worries, it's probably outside the scope of the question. Still, I'd hope that maybe you could add a type trait to your phantom type, like `using value_type = PHANTOM_TYPE`?

Comment: I didn't really want to do that, but I think that will be my only option for now.

Comment: @PeterLenkefi: You don't necessarily need to add it directly to your phantom type class either, you could use a separate traits specialization like so: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zcgp5ZsUuEuX81OS

Comment: That at least separates the concepts, better than nothing. If you add this to your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lambda with std::accumulate, although given a simple sum there wouldn't actually be a need for the lambda.

Comment: Sure, that was an example. I'm interested in matching overload sets.